# How to apply a color for a radmenuitem if it is selected?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, telerik, wpf-controls, radmenu

Code:

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Home" x:Name="radMenuHome" />
```

How to apply a color for a radmenuitem if it is selected? I want to have the selected menu item to be in gray color. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "is selected"? Are you talking about the mouse hover color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea about the `RadMenuItem` class, but I can only assume that it extends the `MenuItem` class. If this is the case, then this answer should still make sense. The WPF `MenuItem` has what I would call a bug in it... this short example demonstrates this:

```
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="MenuItem.IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Background" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="One" />
    <MenuItem Header="Two">
        <MenuItem Header="Three" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

As you can see, the `MenuItem.Foreground` correctly changes to `Red` as you mouse over the `MenuItem`s, but the `Background` does not. This is because of the way that the default `MenuItem Controltemplate` was defined. You can find this default template in the [Menu Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

So the correct way to achieve what you want is to define a new `ControlTemplate` for the `MenuItem` that is based on the default one from the linked page. To make it more tricky for you, you'll actually find four `ControlTemplate`s in the default one... these are for the `TopLevelHeader`, `TopLevelItem` and `SubmenuHeader` and `SubmenuItem` so you can actually style top level and child `MenuItem`s differently.

Anyway, looking at these `ControlTemplate`s, you should see the following `Trigger` (from the linked page):

```
<Trigger Property="IsHighlighted"
         Value="true">
  <Setter Property="Background"
          TargetName="Border">
    <Setter.Value>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                           EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
          <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}"
                          Offset="1.0" />
          </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
      </LinearGradientBrush>

    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Changing the `Setter.Value` here should have the effect that you want, but you'd need to do it all the `ControlTemplate`s that you find it in. My last tip for you is that when defining new `ControlTemplate`s, you should start with the default XAML and then edit and make your changes only once you have seen it working and the control(s) look as they should do by default. Also, keep running the project to see if it still works for every few changes that you make. Good luck.

---

UPDATE >>>

I just found the [WPF XAML MenuItem Styles](http://www.jimnuzzi.com/2008/06/29/wpf-xaml-menuitem-styles/) page of Jim Nuzzi's blog, which has further explanations of customising the WPF `Menu` and `MenuItem` classes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (only for web/.NET scenario):

```
protected void RadMenu1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadMenuEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.NavigateUrl == Request.Url.LocalPath)
    {
        e.Item.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        e.Item.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Note: add OnItemDataBound="RadMenu1_ItemDataBound" to your Telerik:RadMenu tag